# how to access windows NAS using nodejs in linux?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an express API which should be able to read file available on windows NAS path. I am using Node Js "fs" to implement this.

```js
var express =require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var sharedPath= '\\\\computername.domain.com\share\\'
router.get('/getFile',function(req,res){
            fs.readFile(sharedPath+'test.txt','utf8',function(err,data){
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send({name:'This reponse is from get method of file upload API.',result:data}); 
               
    });
    
});
```

This code works fine in windows machine. but when I deployed code to Linux machine it doesn't work.

What is the right way to access windows NAS using Nodejs in Linux system. I don't have much idea about Linux.

Comment: A NAS will be likely just be mounted to the file system in Linux.  Why don't you just use the mount path?  I don't think you can make this work cleanly across platforms.

Comment: @zero298 Thanks for the reply. I am using cloud foundry for deployment which on the fly creates linux virtual instance. I guess to mount file system need to install some tool in linux which is not possible in my case. what other option I have?